# Serializing Xml from Stream by Setting XmlRoot still throws Exception

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I have a class defined like the following:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="state_territories")]
public class Location
{
    ...
}
```

The XML that I'm retrieving (pulled from the stream and written to the debugger using a writer) is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?><state_territories>...</state_territories>
```

However, when I try to serialize my XML response such as:

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Location));
Locations = serializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream()) as Location;
```

I received the following exception:

> "Expecting element 'Location' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/App.Data.Territories'.
>   Encountered 'Element'  with name 'state_territories', namespace ''."

I'm probably missing something simple, but I had thought that if I define the XmlRoot, this would override the inferred root element Location.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[XmlRoot(...)]` is only processed by `XmlSerializer`:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Location));
Locations = (Location) serializer.Deserialize(response.GetResponseStream());
```

If you are processing regular xml and you need control over the names / attributes etc, then `XmlSerializer` is the best choice; `DataContractSerializer` offers only minimal control over the xml mapping.